# CGI script communication

Tags: perl, cgi, lwp, lwp-useragent

I have two CGI scripts written in Perl and I want to implement the following communication sequence between the two. Script A sends a POST request to script B, it should then wait for B to perform some type of validation by querying a Database, then B sends success or failure back to A along with a custom code e.g. 1122 specific to my application and A continues execution as appropriate. Is this something that can be achieved using the LWP framework ?

I have tried to send a POST request from A to B and then wait in script A using

```
 while(<STDIN>) {
     $response .= $_;
 }
```

until it receives an answer back from B (another POST) but this does not work as A simply ignores the SDTIN loop and continues anyway.

Needless to say I am completely new to to CGI and most answers I have found involve a simple POST or GET request to a CGI script but not a two way communication where one end has to wait for the other to respond after a validation has taken place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to make the script wait for a response. LWP is synchronous by default.

Just make the request, and then read `$res->content;` (not STDIN!) as normal (see [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP#An-Example) for an extended example).

You shouldn't be touching STDIN directly at all if you are working with CGI. Ideally you will be using [Plack/PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) so you will be accessing all input through the Plack API (or a framework built on top of it). If you are working with legacy code, then you will probably be using CGI.pm which provides its own API for reading input (through `param`).

---

> Needless to say I am completely new to to CGI and most answers I have found involve a simple POST or GET request to a CGI script but not a two way communication where one end has to wait for the other to respond after a validation has taken place.

You **are** making a simple POST or GET request.

1. Browser makes request to `A.cgi`
2. `A.cgi` makes request to `B.cgi`
3. `B.cgi` outputs a response
4. `A.cgi` reads that response and does something with it
5. `A.cgi` outputs a response
6. Browser receives that response

Comment: But how should the response from B look like after it has performed the db lookup and found for example that A's POST request is valid ? If I do the steps you're describing when B receives the POST and starts looking up the db for the validation A has already received a 200 OK (success)...

Comment: The response from B can look however you want. Most webservices these days will output a JSON document.

Comment: LWP is not asynchronous by default, doing the steps I describe will NOT cause A to return a response until it has read the response from B. It will only do that if you do something to explicitly send a response before A has finished running.